# OpenSSL padding

Tags: padding, openssl

I would like to know how much padding OpenSSL algorithms expect.

Comment: The answers here will reflect the higher level primitives of course, if you directly use block encrypt then it will probably not pad at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html) says:

> All the block ciphers normally use PKCS#5 padding also known as standard block padding

which is both informative, and slightly misleading. OpenSSL supports, by default, one stream cipher (RC4) and a variety of block ciphers (Blowfish, 3DES, AES...). The `enc` command (from the command-line tool) encrypts an input file into an OpenSSL-specific format, with a custom header (of length 16 bytes), and then the encrypted data as processed through the selected algorithm. For RC4, there is no padding: the encrypted data will have the same length as the source file (but there will be the extra 16-byte header). For block ciphers, it depends on the [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation):

- CBC and ECB modes require that the input consists in an integral number of blocks, so padding must be applied to ensure that. [PKCS#5 padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#PKCS7) (identical to PKCS#7 padding) adds at least one byte, at most 255 bytes; OpenSSL will add the minimal number of bytes needed to reach the next multiple of the block size, so if blocks have size *n*, then padding will involve between 1 and *n* extra bytes (including). Block size depends on the algorithm: Blowfish and 3DES use 8-byte blocks, AES uses 16-byte blocks.
- CFB and OFB modes don't require padding, so there is none applied.

Comment: By definition, when you decrypt, the decryption engine removes the padding. So that engine reliably detects the padding length; this is why PKCS#5 always adds at least one byte (otherwise, the padding would be ambiguous). However, you cannot know the padding length without decrypting. As for _encryption_, then just look at the length of the data before and after encryption.

Comment: As of now, OpenSSL does not seem to append any custom header when encrypting the data.